# How to change currency automatically as depends on country in OPENCART

Tags: opencart, currency, opencart2.x

I have a website and a problem with opencart currency.
I hope you know that.
There are 3 currencies on my website(vertusshop.com) and I wanna change currency automatically as depends on country. How can I do it?

For example: When I entered the website in USA, the currency should be changed as $ (dollar). but if the website has not $ (dollar), it should be changed default currency.
Please help me? How can I do it? (My opencart version is: 2.0)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To encourage the folks here to help you, you should show what you have already done/researched in order to solve your problem. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this module : [AutoDetect](https://isenselabs.com/products/view/autodetect-get-currency-and-language-detected-based-on-visitors-country) 
Not only changes the currency, also it changes languages too.